# Munin graph size

Tags: munin, graph

Munin graphs is very small. That makes some multigrpahs useless for me.
Is it possible to increase graph image size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The documentation](http://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/reference/plugin.html?highlight=height#global-attributes) makes reference to two global attributes, graph_width and graph_height.  Have you tried changing them?  Note that these are global for a particular plugin, not for the whole munin installation; you will need to set them in the config output of a single plugin (or in `munin.conf`) for them to take effect.

Just to check, I put the following lines into my `munin.conf`:

```
load.graph_width 1200
load.graph_height 1000
```

and my load graph got absolutely massive, so I expect this will work for you, too.

Comment: don't know why, but "graph_width" doesn't work for "Disk IOs", "Disk latency", "Disk utilization" graphs, only height is changed.

Comment: @John: If you look at thee `diskstats` plugin, it says the graph width is set dynamically and has a default of 400 unless you override `env.graph_width` in the plugin config.

Comment: Is there a way to change this for all graphs?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, though note that you can set it on a plugin-by-plugin basis in `munin.conf`, which is at least centralised.

Comment: you can also add them on the node or group level: 
graph_height 1200. It has the same issue for the graphs with dynamic graph width.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, it seems that with munin 2.0.6 it is possible to set these on the global level, with two caveats:

- if using CGI graphs (as munin 2.x does by default), updates to the munin.conf file are not picked up automatically, so restarting all the munin-cgi-graph processes is necessary
- sometime, munin-cgi-graph seems to "forget" these and revert to the default; a restart, again, helps

Tested on Debian sid with munin 2.0.6-1.